# Two tableviews with same row heights (Android)

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, row-height

I have a view with two tables. One is used as titles column (static) and other for data. (Linear layout, horizontal).

I need somehow to read the heights of each row in data table, and make the rows at titles table be at the same height...

[image]

Comment: Show your xml pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this below code to read your View Height :

```
 view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                                //TO remove listener
                                    view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                                int height = view.getHeight();
                                int width = view.getWidth();
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome :-) :-)

Answer (score -1):

Its not a good idea to control the height based on other view's height. Better to use a Table Layout

Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/table_layout_4_open"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/table_layout_4_open_shortcut"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/table_layout_4_save"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/table_layout_4_save_shortcut"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Output

[image: Screenshot]

You can implement in a similar fashion